# Unable to get metrics from embedded tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, datadog

We are trying to get metrics from springboot embedded tomcat in Datadog, if it is a pure Tomcat I can see it but the other one no, everything is configured following Datadog manual without success.
Tried to enable mbeanregistry java_opts:

```
-Dserver.tomcat.mbeanregistry.enabled=true
```

And enabling more jmx options provided by Datadog support

```
      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9012
      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9012
      -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=xxxx
```

Building this last jmxremote=true throws an error, but seems that will not work anyway.
Any suggestions?

```
-Dserver.tomcat.mbeanregistry.enabled=true
```

```
      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9012
      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9012
      -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=xxxx
```